# related to upload video to specific event in youtube channel

Tags: actionscript-3

I created livebroadcast event in YouTube. I need to **upload video** to those created event using youtube api. Is there any way to do this?.

Answer (score 0):

you can learn it in [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/getting-started#resources) using youtube **API**.